# How can I use FFMPEG to overlay one video on another

Tags: ffmpeg

I have 2 videos of the same duration and framerate. I would like to overlay video A which is of size (100,210) on video B which is of size (1920,1440) and I would like the top left corner of video A to be at the position (50,50) in video B. How can I do this ? I can't find the solution and ffmpeg is too complicated for me to learn just to do something simple.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10920872/5726027

Comment: that puts an image on a video. mine is video on video

Comment: Just replace the 2nd inpiut with your video.

Comment: that was very simple ! thank you very much !